# How to enable PostgreSQL in Xampp on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, postgresql, xampp

Can anyone please tell me how I can enable PostgreSQL in Xampp on Mac platform? Or is there any other GUI alternative like XAMPP for Mac platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use MAPP Stack for OSX.

MAPP: https://bitnami.com/stack/mapp

In case you need MySQL + PostgreSQL, download MAMP + PostgreSQL extension

MAMP: https://bitnami.com/stack/mamp

PostgreSQL add-on: https://bitnami.com/stack/mamp/modules#postgresql

Enable MySQL before installing PostgreSQL by starting MAMP stack's MySQL. After installing, go to PostgreSQL admin page and login as user=postgres and password=[password], create your own root user with password.